# Mostrar texto select en textarea

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo un select con varias opciones que obtengo de la base de datos, algo así:

```
<select class="custom-select ingredientesselect">
                        <option selected>Seleccione un ingrediente</option>
                        <option value="1">Hola</option>
                        <option value="2">Como</option>
                        <option value="3">Estas</option>
                        <option value="4">Espero</option>
                        <option value="5">Bien</option>
                                                  
</select>
<textarea class="form-control muestraingredientes"></textarea>
```

Excepto que el value y el nombre lo muestro con php.

Lo que quiero hacer es que al seleccionar un option, me muestre el texto del value en un textarea. Que me muestre el "hola", "como", etc.

Estoy intentando usar este script de JQuery pero no me muestra nada.

```
$('select.ingredientesselect').change(function() {
            var valor = $('textarea').val();
            $('textarea.muestraingredientes').val(valor + $(this).text()); 
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Opción 1**

- A la etiqueta `select` dale una clase, lo mismo que para el `textarea`
- Recuperas y asignas en variables a los 2 elementos antes mencionados
- Como deseas asignar en el `textarea` el valor que el usuario obtiene del `select` entonces debes agregar un listener que vigile el evento `change`
- Cuando estés vigilando el evento antes mencionado, guardas en uan variable el valor recuperado a través de: [event.target.value](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) (*actualizado a la forma recomendada de MDN*)
- Finalmente a la propiedad `innerText` del `textarea` recién recuperado le asignas la variable `opcion` que de forma dinámica nos estará retornando el valor del `select` elegido

Código:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Ejemplo en JS</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <select name="" id="" class="opciones">
      <option value="Cero" class="opcion">-------------</option>
      <option value="Uno" class="opcion">Uno</option>
      <option value="Dos" class="opcion">Dos</option>
      <option value="Tres" class="opcion">Tres</option>
      <option value="Cuatro" class="opcion">Cuatro</option>
      <option value="Cinco" class="opcion">Cinco</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <textarea class="areaTexto" cols="30" rows="10">
      
    </textarea>
    <script>
        let opciones  = document.querySelector(".opciones")
        let textoArea = document.querySelector(".areaTexto")
        
        opciones.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
          let opcion = event.target.value
          textoArea.innerText = opcion
        })
    </script>
      
    </body>
    </html>
```

**EDICIÓN OPCIÓN 2**

Si necesitas que los elementos de tu `select` se agreguen al espacio del `textarea` sin perder el anterior elegido, entonces realiza estos cambios:

Modifica esta línea:

```
textoArea.innerText = opcion
```

De esta forma:

```
textoArea.append(opcion)
```

Quedando así:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>JS Bin</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <select name="" id="" class="opciones">
      <option value="Cero" class="opcion">-------------</option>
      <option value="Uno" class="opcion">Uno</option>
      <option value="Dos" class="opcion">Dos</option>
      <option value="Tres" class="opcion">Tres</option>
      <option value="Cuatro" class="opcion">Cuatro</option>
      <option value="Cinco" class="opcion">Cinco</option>
    </select>
    <textarea class="areaTexto" cols="30" rows="10">
      
    </textarea>
    <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]">
    <script>
        let opciones  = document.querySelector(".opciones")
        let textoArea = document.querySelector(".areaTexto")
        
        opciones.addEventListener("change", () => {
          let opcion = event.target.value
          textoArea.append(opcion)
        })
    </script>
      
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: gracias, me funciono, pero tengo dos preguntas. Como puedo hacer para que no me borre el anterior valor? Y que es eso de "let"? Solo manejo un poco de JQuery, por eso preguntaba con una solución parecida a la que tenia.

Comment: @ValeAsencioUribe `let` es el identificador para declarar variables en JavaScript, considero que deberías aprender mejor el lenguaje en lugar de JQuery, por otro lado dejame ver como modifico para lo que preguntas

Comment: @ValeAsencioUribe revisa lo que edité al final de mi respuesta para ver si te ayuda

Comment: siiiiii, ahi si se puede, y si no es mucha la molestia jejeje sabes como puedo hacerle un salto de linea cada vez que agrego un select al textarea?

Comment: Si claro dame un momento @ValeAsencioUribe

Comment: @ValeAsencioUribe simplemente donde hago `textoArea.append(opcion)` dale un salto de línea con `\n` quedando así: `textoArea.append(opcion+"\n")`

Comment: @BetoM siiii, ya lo intente también así. Muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda!! Y seguiré tu consejo de aprender el lenguaje. Que te vaya super =D

Comment: estoy tratando de hacerla ahora numerado y con espacios a ver como me va

Comment: ¿alguien sabe como poner nulo un `<option>` de `<select>` cuando lo clickeas? Estuve haciendo este método `document.getElementById("objeto").disabled = true;` y solo me ponía nulo uno y los demás seguían estando disponibles así que decidí hacerle a cada uno su propio disabled y no respondieron como esperaba, clickeando uno se ponían nulos todos en vez de que fuesen uno por uno, no se si necesito un ciclo algun método, ayuda por favor

Answer (score 1):

intenta probarlo de esta manera:

```
$('select.ingredientesselect').change(function() {
            var valor = $('textarea').val() ;
            $('textarea.muestraingredientes').val(valor + $('select.ingredientesselect option:selected').text()); });
```

Revisa este ejemplo reutilizando tu código:

https://jsfiddle.net/9ga8c3w5/

Comment: asi lo intente, pero pasa lo que dice BetaM, por eso no supe como hacerlo.

Comment: De acuerdo, los valores los puedes concatenar utilizando el simbolo "+" o también inner en el mismo código. Como está el código si aplica lo que buscas dado que aumenta la cadena según las selección en el select.

Comment: @Manuel Camacho ohhh si vi, muchisimas graciaas!!!!! <3